# Populating dictionary causing error

Tags: vba, dictionary

I am using VBA to populate a dictionary with the codes from a table, all these codes are unique. Though when I try to add them into the dictionary I get an error:
'This key is already associated with an element of this collection'

A few example of codes I'm entering in are:

GSK611, GSK612, GSK612 (However their are the odd code with DELETED00, ADMIN, HISTORY)

The method I use is:

```
Private Function RunContactQuery(query As String) As dictionary
    On Error GoTo Catch

    Dim ex As ErrEx

    Dim dictionary As dictionary
    Set dictionary = New dictionary

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim counter As Integer

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(query)

    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
        rs.MoveFirst
        counter = 1

        Do Until rs.EOF = True
            dictionary.Add rs.Fields(0), counter

            counter = counter + 1
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If

    Set RunContactQuery = dictionary

Finally:
    Exit Function
Catch:
    ErrEx(Err, cmstrModule & ".RunContactQuery").Throw
    Resume Finally
End Function
```

I get the error at 'dictionary.Add rs.Fields, counter'

All of this are unique also as I've got the values in the immediate window.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve the problem... It was storing an object into the field 'Field2' and I wanted the value so I changed:

```
dictionary.Add rs.Fields(0), counter
```

to

```
dictionary.Add rs.Fields(0).value, counter
```

It now gets the value